# How to log out users from web client application that uses JWT tokens

Tags: android, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, jwt

I have an ASP.Net Core 3.1 web-api application that uses MS Identity framework to generate JWT tokens for the logged in user.

Then I have a client application (html , javascript) that connects to that web-api.

I also have an android application that connects to the same web-api application.

I want to log out a user from web client when it logins from the android application.
How to do that?

Comment: If you want to use `real-time` notification (like when the user is in the app) and the server makes the request towards the client then you have 2 possibilities: 1. push notification sent from server to client (client then parses push notification's payload and check if received a logout action) or to use sockets (client registers on a 'logout' channel, then server initiates logout and client listens to this channel). If you don't want to make real time logout, then just add a new API end point and when the user opens the app send the JWT token. If it's invalid then logout the user.

Comment: But then I will have short -lived tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the challenge with JWT token. TO validate JWT token client doesn't need to talk to token issuer. If the client does then no use of using a JWT token.

You can follow the below approach to handle logoff scenario:

Approach 1) Keep JWT token a very short life span.

Approach 2) Maintain a distributed cache - where all the logged off JWT token can be stored and before validating the token check with the distributed cache.